# Will you use Google's Chrome Frame?

Tags: google-chrome-frame

Are you planning in requiring Google's [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) in production for your own websites?

Have you tested it?

Would your opinion on wether to use it or not change if Google were to require it for Youtube? (It will be required for [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/))

Comment: Should be wiki as there is no correct answer.  But nonetheless, Microsoft has already come out against it as being a security problem... http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/09/microsoft-google-chrome-frame-makes-ie-less-secure.ars

Comment: Yeah, I read that. Of course they will. What they are saying can be said of Flash and Silverlight too.

Comment: Hmm... I voted to close this as "belongs on superuser.com" but having thought about it I assume you mean "Are you planning to write code using Chrome Frame" - it may be worth clarifying the question to avoid others making my mistake.

Comment: Made a slight change of words to clarify. Thanks Jon, and congratulations for your 100k.

Comment: @Mayo: http://tech.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=1380749&cid=29527573 I couldn't have said it better :)

Comment: How to write code to Google Frame: Remove the work-arounds you made for IE

Answer (score 4):

I wish they would require everyone who views YouTube to use it. I hate programming specifically just for IE... If it were required for YouTube I don't think that any of the users I care about would lack it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a hard time finding info about big sites that *require* GCF, so I was a bit worried about requiring it for IE 6 and 7.

But I went ahead with it on a site with 6-digit number of monthly users, and the results were great.

IE 6 and 7 usage bombed, and about 90% of that usage was picked up by GCF. Only a few complaints from annoying users, but telling them to "just click install" has been a good enough solution.

The users lost were also less likely to purchase than those with better browsers.

Comment: Can you share what site? (or let me know privately?) I'm working with the GCF team to make our conversion flow better. :)

Comment: @Paul Irish (I almost wrote +Paul Irish...): I implemented it on a XX,XXX visitors website. The main complaints were the frame not displaying correctly (this was easy to replicate, not sure if fixed yet); right-click menu suddenly being different; "Google is evil"; "Google are hacking my computer", "[insert reasons why Google is doing this like to inject advertising into websites]", "I'm going to sue you for breaking my computer", etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Ah. Well, all those things are _totally_ true. :p

Answer (score 2):

I am aware of at least one site that now points to it rather than saying they don't support IE6.

If you've made the decision to not support IE6, for whatever reason, it at least gives the opportunity for more users to maybe* access your site.

*I say 'maybe' because if users aren't able to upgrade their browser it's quite unlikley they're able/allowed to install such extensions/plugins either.

Comment: What site is already using it?

Comment: Site using it already include intranets and admin interfaces - sorry, nothing I can point you to publically

Comment: CF doesn't require admin rights so definitely they can install it. Even better it won't break their paleolithic websites

Answer (score 0):

I always wait a bit before picking up new technologies such as this.  I'm a patient person and don't feel the need to rush out and get the latest thing first.

Once the consensus is that it looks ok, runs ok and won't hurt me or my nearest and dearest I'll have a look.