# Always using google chrome frame meta tag for standard compliant page, is good idea?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, meta-tags, google-chrome-frame

I was thinking to add meta tag always in all the websites. 
That will trigger google chorme frame to load for users who already installed. I can see the benefits but **is there any concerns or facts that I should know before I do that?**

Testing in **google chrome** is enough or testing in **google chrome frame** explicitly required?

Thanks

*Note: please do not mention current know problems "print" and "download" issue. I'm sure those will get fixed soon :)*

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471780/will-you-use-googles-chrome-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only argument against chrome frame that I have seen so far is Microsoft's - "Google Chrome Frame running as a plugin has doubled the attach area for malware and malicious scripts."

Also, you may run into problems with frames. If you have chrome frame on your page and someone has that page iframed on their site you may run into some problems. More info:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/d5ffe442658bc60e/e6d7a4c1c179c931?lnk=gst&q=iframe

You should only need to test in Chrome Frame for (X)HTML, CSS, and JavaScript...basic stuff. If you are using AJAX (while trying not to [break the back button](http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/FixingTheBackButtonThatAjaxBroke)), worried about caching, cookies (accessed via javascript), or other potentially browser-specific browser interactions I suggest testing on the IE+CF platform...at least until the CF team announces 100% interoperability between CF and IE.

Check out the CF Google group for more issues.

Answer (score -1):

Are there any concerns or facts you should know?  Yes: **Not everyone has Google Chrome Frame installed**.

You are *adding* a new user agent that you will need to test and debug against, *without removing* the need to test and debug the user experience for other browsers (notably plain IE by itself).

If you don't make the IE user experience equivalent to the Google Chrome experience, then you are alienating a significant percentage of users.  Depending on your website and its expected users, the impact of this may range from undesirable to unacceptable.  If you do make the user experience equivalent, then there is no point in adding the meta tag.

Comment: You didn't understood question. Targeting Chrome Frame doesn't mean not targeting IE.

Just including meta tag means if user have Chrome Frame install he can have better experience and better speed. If not doesn't harm.

I'm looking for technical concerns not political.